# Configure Connection Draining for AWS Load Balancer v2 in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

[This blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-connection-draining-remove-instances-from-service-with-care/) ([here specifically](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/ELBGDAL.template)) details how to configure connection draining for a 'classic' version 1 load balancer using the `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer` type, like so:

```
"ElasticLoadBalancer": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
  "Properties": {
    "ConnectionDrainingPolicy": {
      "Enabled": "true",
      "Timeout": "300"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I do this using the version 2 load balancer with type `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer`?

My best guess from [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html) is that I should use `LoadBalancerAttributes`, but I can't find anything related to connection draining in the [list of attributes here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#load-balancer-attributes).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Application Load Balancer(ELB V2 ) it in configured using [TargetGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html) and [TargetGroupAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_TargetGroupAttribute.html) and is called Deregistration delay, not Connection draining.

> deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds - The amount time for Elastic
> Load Balancing to wait before changing the state of a deregistering
> target from draining to unused. The range is 0-3600 seconds. The
> default value is 300 seconds.

```
   TargetGroup:
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
      Properties:
        TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
          Value: '20'
```

Comment: This has made my day! Thank you